# c# really clearing console on linux (or portable)?

Tags: c#, linux, console

I'm learning c# at school, with vs2017.

On simple console apps, Console.Clear() works but, running the same at home on Linux (mono), it seems it "fakes" clearing the console: it's really "scrolling" output up until all previous stuff is not visible anymore, but using console scrollbars you can see it's just... above.

Maybe is the same on windows, I can't test right now but will soon.

What I wished to do is not "scroll" the current content enough to "hide" it, but rather "overwrite" it with new content, even a clear screen, so that users cannot access previous content. Just as if I didn't have scrollbars, somewhat like a canvas, or like "resetting" the console session from scratch.

I'm just wondering if that can be done.

Here is my very (very!) simple test setup:

```
using System;

namespace clearscreen
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //fill the screen
            for (int i = 0; i < 30;i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            }
            //wait for user input
            Console.ReadKey(true);

            //clear the screen
            Console.Clear();

            //put some new content on screen
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: sorry I added a dumb example now, but also better explained what I meant.